# Custom arguments in DgsQuery - GraphQl Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I have a graphql implementation using SpringBoot

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.netflix.graphql.dgs</groupId>
   <artifactId>graphql-dgs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have some queries like this

```
@DgsQuery
@CustomAnnotation
public Output getOutput(@InputArgument Long input) {
        return new Output(input, <someOtherInput>);
}
```

My use case is for all DgsQuery annotated using CustomAnnotation I need to pass an extra argument `someOtherInput` This argument is not passed from the client but calculated on server side on each request.

I have done something similar in Spring Rest using `WebMvcConfigurer` `addArgumentResolvers'

Is there something similar for `graphql-dgs`

I am expecting something like this

```
@DgsQuery
@CustomAnnotation
public Output getOutput(@InputArgument Long input, @CustomArgument String someOtherInput) {
        return new Output(input, someOtherInput);
}
```